# android maps always returning same position

Tags: google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to send the current position from an android app developed by me to server but the provider always send the same position and not the position where I can see the point marker.

I request location updates like this:

```
    // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE.
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider.
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(true);

    // Getting the name of the best provider.
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2, 2, this);
```

And i get the lat and long like that:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Location currentLocation;
    Location nextLocation;

    if (MapVisible == true) {

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location.
        latitude = location.getLatitude(); <--------here
        longitude = location.getLongitude(); <--------here   

        ...
```

But the server always receive the same position. Any tip about the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's many reasons to that. Maybe because you're connected to a wi-fi network and your GPS is off, so your phone only get location from your IP address, location from IP address is usually always the same.

Furthermore, you're using `criteria` and `locationManager.getBestProvider();`, that will return the same provider based on your criteria. Ignoring other locations provided by other provider which didn't match your criteria.

If you wondering why your location isn't same with the blue point marker, you can try to switching from Android Location APIs to Play Services Location APIs, it's more accurate and more simple. More info : https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html